# Regarding stitching of files

Tags: java, file

I have huge files which have been returned as an answer to a query. I want the aggregated list to be shown to the user. Earlier when the files were small I would read them individually and aggregate the result in a third file but now even the reading means a delay of a few seconds which the users cannot tolerate. Is there any way in which the file can be stitched and the aggregated result be presented to the user ?

Earlier I tried a command like "cat file1 fiile2 >> file3" which seemlessly integrates the content of file1 and file2 into file3 but this command does not work when I do

Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat file1 fiile2 >> file3");
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

Comment: You need to give some details of your implementation. Is the aggregated file just a concatenation of the individual files? Or is there some processing (ie to remove duplicates etc).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `Runtime.exec()`

Comment: Yes the aggregated file is just a concatenation of the individual files....

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the shell script you are using, your "aggregation" is actually just concatenating the files.

If that is the case then you simply need to something like this:

```
  OutputStream os = ...

  byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];  // or maybe a bit bigger
  int nosRead;
  try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("file1")) {
      while ((nosRead = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
          os.write(buffer, 0, nosRead);
      }
  }
  try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("fiile2")) {
      while ((nosRead = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
          os.write(buffer, 0, nosRead);
      }
  }
```

There is no need to use an external command to concatenate the files.  Doing the "stitching" directly (as above) means that you will start sending data to the user immediately.  Assuming that this is all there is to your "stitching", it should not be necessary to use Readers / Writers, and avoiding that makes this a little faster.